# How to stop ubuntu upgrades completely?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, upgrade, apt

I wanted to stop Linux kernel upgrades on Ubuntu 16.04.X. Initially, 
`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file is updated to have entry like this `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";` Then also the kernel is upgraded.    Afterwards i have ran the following:

```
sudo -S apt-mark hold linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

After few days, I see kernel is being upgraded on my Ubuntu. As I have installed third party drivers for few components, Every time the kernel upgrades, that peripheral is becoming unavailable to use.

May i get suggestions on how to stop the Ubuntu upgrades completely?

Comment: `man dpkg` @ "Package selection states" -> hold. Also: `--set-selections`

Comment: Thanks a lot Hannu, I will try the solution and post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Disable apt-daily.service:

systemctl stop apt-daily.timer

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

or:

```
sudo systemctl disable --now apt-daily{,-upgrade}.{timer,service}
```

To disable automatic upgrades do:

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` to disable automatic updates from the command line:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Once you have the file opened, switch off the Update-Package-Lists directive from 1 to 0 as shown below:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

or:

```
sudo sed -i 's/APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1"/APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0"/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20-auto-upgrades
```

In 16.04 those relevant options are set in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file